# How to grpcurl list for gRPC service with reflection on CloudRun?

Tags: go, grpc, google-cloud-run

Following this example:

gRPC in Google Cloud Run

https://github.com/grpc-ecosystem/grpc-cloud-run-example/blob/master/golang/README.md

I've deployed a gRPC service with reflection on CloudRun.

Using grpcurl for testing:
https://github.com/fullstorydev/grpcurl

```
grpcurl \
-proto protos/calculator.proto \
-d '{"first_operand": 2.0, "second_operand": 3.0, "operation": "ADD"}' \
${ENDPOINT}:443 \
Calculator.Calculate
```

GRPC Server Reflection Protocol
https://github.com/grpc/grpc/blob/master/doc/server-reflection.md

Now I want to use reflection following these instructions.

```
--- a/examples/helloworld/greeter_server/main.go
+++ b/examples/helloworld/greeter_server/main.go
@@ -40,6 +40,7 @@ import (
        "google.golang.org/grpc"
        pb "google.golang.org/grpc/examples/helloworld/helloworld"
+       "google.golang.org/grpc/reflection"
 )

 const (
@@ -61,6 +62,8 @@ func main() {
        }
        s := grpc.NewServer()
        pb.RegisterGreeterService(s, &pb.GreeterService{SayHello: sayHello})
+       // Register reflection service on gRPC server.
+       reflection.Register(s)
        if err := s.Serve(lis); err != nil {
                log.Fatalf("failed to serve: %v", err)
        }
```

https://github.com/grpc/grpc-go/blob/master/Documentation/server-reflection-tutorial.md#enable-server-reflection

what you tried:

a local test. Please note:
grpcurl -plaintext means not TLS. Ommiting -plaintext means TLS.

what worked:

```
############################
# local testing
############################
request list:
grpcurl -plaintext localhost:8080 list

result:
Calculator
grpc.reflection.v1alpha.ServerReflection

request ADD function:
grpcurl -plaintext \
    -d '{"first_operand": 2.0, "second_operand": 3.0, "operation": "ADD"}' \
    localhost:8080 \
    Calculator.Calculate

result:
{
  "result": 5
}
############################
```

what you tried:
a GCP CloudRun test. Please note:
grpcurl -plaintext means not TLS. Ommiting -plaintext means TLS.

what worked:

```
request:
grpcurl \
    -proto protos/calculator.proto \
    -d '{"first_operand": 2.0, "second_operand": 3.0, "operation": "ADD"}' \
    ${ENDPOINT}:443 \
    Calculator.Calculate

result:
{
  "result": 5
}
```

what didn’t work:
I want to use reflection so omitted:

```
-proto protos/calculator.proto \
```

I want to use TLS so omitted:

```
-plaintext
```

request:

```
grpcurl \
    -d '{"first_operand": 2.0, "second_operand": 3.0, "operation": "ADD"}' \
    ${ENDPOINT}:443 \
    Calculator.Calculate
```

response:

timeout

Bottom line. The local test shows reflection is working fine.
It cannot work when deployed to CloudRun.

I suppose because it requires bidirectional stream:

https://github.com/grpc/grpc/blob/master/src/proto/grpc/reflection/v1alpha/reflection.proto

```
service ServerReflection {
  // The reflection service is structured as a bidirectional stream, ensuring
  // all related requests go to a single server.
  rpc ServerReflectionInfo(stream ServerReflectionRequest)
      returns (stream ServerReflectionResponse);
}
```

Comment: Why do you think it’s not working? What’s the error you get? How do you expect grpcurl to authenticate (you need to provide an Authorization header/metadata). Please add more details.

Comment: grpcurl needs to specify the port number:
https://github.com/fullstorydev/grpcurl   
like this: grpcurl localhost:8787 list.  Obviously 443 cannot be the port number.

my request is: grpcurl -plaintext grpc-cloud-run-example-server-xxx.a.run.app:443 list

Failed to dial target host "grpc-cloud-run-example-server-xxx.a.run.app:443": context deadline exceeded.

Comment: :443 is correct. But you need to let grpcurl to use TLS. Cloud Run forces TLS, and if you try to talk plaintext to a TLS endpoint, you’ll get that error.

Comment: As a general rule of thumb, please edit your question to list “what you tried” “what worked” and “what didn’t work”.

Comment: I revised my posting, please look at it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

gRPC Reflection requires bidirectional streaming, so make sure to check the Enable HTTP/2 option (--use-http2) while deploying. That will enable bi-di streaming.

Also make sure to use the :443 port and authenticate to the server if needed by adding Authentication metadata (see Service-to-Service authentication documentation).

Comment: I did and got the message: Use `gcloud alpha` to set `--use-http2` on Cloud Run (fully managed). Does my project should be enabled for http2?

Comment: The feature is in preview, make sure to update gcloud, and use `gcloud beta`.

Comment: gcloud beta --use-http2 did the job!